# Conditional C/C++ struct definitions

Tags: c++, c, gcc, struct, one-definition-rule

I've stumbled across some code that looks like this:

```
typedef struct SomeStruct
{
    int foo;
    void * bar;
#if defined(__cplusplus)
    SomeStruct();
#endif
} SomeStruct;
```

It's in a header file that will be included by both .c and .cpp files. That seems to be at least technically a violation of the One-Definition-Rule. The obvious impact I see is that if one of these is ever declared in .c file, the constructor won't run. And unfortunately, someone seems to have used this as a pattern for the correct way to declare structs, and has declared a couple dozen structs just like it.

I'm trying to figure out how serious a problem this is. Beyond the constructor possibly not running, is there any other likely impact? The constructor is implemented in a .cpp file. I see pointers to structs allocted in a .c file (with malloc) that are passed to functions in the .cpp files. They appear to work correctly (compiled with gcc/g++ 4.6.2 for Suse Linux, if that matters), as far as I can tell. Would something break if virtual member functions were also added? Right now, none of these classes have anything in their cplusplus section other than the default constructor, as shown above.

Comment: Virtual functions will surely break the code. They require additional storage inside of the struct (so called *vtable pointer*).

Comment: Adding a `char* empty;` at the beginning of the `struct` might help you add virtual function, although it's a pretty horrendous solution

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly a violation of the ODR. Informally, the C compiler see a POD type and the C++ compiler see a class in the global namespace which will become an entity with a mangled name. More importantly, the structure is only declared differently for C and C++ compilers, but it is only defined once in a C++ source file. Most likely there's some allocation and free functions in a C++ source file which expose the constructor/destructor to a C API. For example,

Header file

```
$ cat some_struct.h 
#ifndef SOME_STRUCT_H
#define SOME_STRUCT_H

typedef struct SomeStruct {
    int foo;
    void *var;
#if defined(__cplusplus)
    SomeStruct();
#endif
} SomeStruct;

#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

SomeStruct *some_struct_malloc();
void some_struct_free(SomeStruct **);

#if defined(__cplusplus)
} // extern "C"
#endif

#endif // SOME_STRUCT_H
```

C++ source file

```
$ cat some_struct.cpp 
#include "some_struct.h"
#include <cstddef>

SomeStruct::SomeStruct()
{
    foo = 10;
    var = NULL;
}

SomeStruct *some_struct_malloc() { return new SomeStruct; }

void some_struct_free(SomeStruct **pp)
{
    if (*pp)
        delete *pp;
    *pp = NULL;
}
```

C source file:

```
$ cat main.c 
#include "some_struct.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    SomeStruct *p = some_struct_malloc();
    printf("%d\n", p->foo);
}
```

I would say it is a bad style. But it works as a convenient way to expose a C++ library to a C API

Comment: I hadn't realized they would be different structs (the C++ one with name mangling). Then code is then casting one as the other when they pass them back and forth. There could be C functions that call "new" in a C++ file, but there aren't. I see C code which does: "SomeStruct * ss = calloc(1, sizeof(SomeStruct));". I think this is the problem with what's been done. Either they use new/delete or malloc/free. They can't mix them, so they're always either creating/destroying one struct or the other. So the constructor is unused for some (most) structs.

Comment: @PeterS6g I'd wait for some confirmation about structs' name mangling. For me it looks like a nonsense. I'm almost sure that structs' names are not mangled. Simply because structs' definitions are not saved to object files (even if they would, mangling was added to make overloaded functions' internal names different; this makes no sense for structs).

Comment: I was actually looking up the symbols in gdb, and I couldn't see any evidence of mangling (but I'm not sure if gdb is hiding that from me by automatically demangling them).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat @PeterS6g What I meant was actually struct's member functions and functions that takes struct as parameters are mangled. Structs itself does not even come up in the symbol table. For example, say there's a function `void f(SomeStruct)` in C source file and another in C++ source file `void f(SomeStruct)`, they will come up as different symbols